# Execute SQL Task continue execution after completion of Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, cursors

I have stored procedure which i am trying to execute in SSIS using Execute SQL Task. This stored procedure involves Cursor and last step is De-allocate Cursor. I observe that even after the execution of stored procedure is completed Execute SQL task doesn't complete and halts for long time before moving to next step. To test this i have added insert stmt as last line in stored procedure with GETDATE() as one column value. It shows STP execution completed almost 2 hours prior to Execute SQL Task completion. Any idea if Execute SQL Task is running some additional steps along with required stored procedure

Comment: Why do you assume that SSIS or the Execute SQL task ar at fault? Using cursors is a very strong smell - there are very, very, very few things that require a cursor. The only valid scenario, batch processing, is addressed by an SSIS datalfow. Most likely your stored procedure is *not* ending when you think it is, because the cursor takes far longer to complete than an equivalent SQL statement. Worst case, using a Cursor ends up locking the entire table for hours, resulting in livelocking with other statements

Comment: Can you post your code or tell us what you are trying to do. It will give us a better idea of what is happening and maybe find a better solution.

Comment: Also look into running profiler rather than just using an insert statement at the end of the SP>

Comment: @panagiotis: :) i am not considering any task at fault here, just trying to identify what happens after last line of code. My scenario for using Cursor is as below: I have say 10 records each of them needs to run through different set of rules for checking on correctness. This makes me run through one record at a time, hence cursor. I have used Hint for Row level locking on table so i assume it wont lock entire table. Happy to learn if you have any better way to address this. thanks for your help

Comment: It's impossible to answer without the *queries* themselves. Anyway, you don't need a cursor even for that. You can run 1 query for each rule knowing that the optimizer will bypass. You could convert the rules to functions and just join with the data. Or you could create a truth table containing entries for all rules and join them with the data

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, yeah i would think about changing the entire solution if this problem persist. But since i have invested some time i would like to get thiw working. Problem is stored procedure(Cursor included) works and completes in SSMS in 1 hour 30 mins but when same stored procedure called from SSIS after final statement takes up 3+ hours. Please note it has few other SQL task running parallel can this be thread issue? buffer issue?

Comment: Next time please poste your query. Its much easier to answer to your question instead of guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved :) this was basically because i was using few Print statements in SQL stored procedures and as i was executing these stored procs from SSIS it might be creating some buffers which was being cleared after execution. I commented Print stmts in my stored proc and execution time in SSIS is same as execution time in SSMS.

Thanks for your time in helping me.

Regards